# msgpack c++ unable to write to pipe

Tags: c++, serialization, msgpack

I have read a lot about the msgpack over the net, but couldn't find any help regarding this issue.

```
#include<msgpack.hpp>

int main(){

 struct item {
    std::time_t currentTime;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> base;
    };


struct obj {
    std::string eventName;
    item item1;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> dateTime;    
};

obj obj1[1];
obj1[0].eventName = "TEMP_EVENT";
obj1[0].item1.base["Id"] = "6ba1ce80";
obj1[0].dateTime["TimeFormat"] = "DateTime";
std::stringstream buffer;
msgpack::pack(buffer, obj1);// this line is throwing the error
return 0;
        
}
```

Seeing the following error, I am using the msgpack-c library

```
left of '.msgpack_pack' must have class/struct/union 
       ~\packages\msgpack-c.0.5.9.1\build\native\include\msgpack\object.hpp(192):
   note: type is 'const obj [1]'
       ~\packages\msgpack-c.0.5.9.1\build\native\include\msgpack\object.hpp(155):
   note: while compiling class template member function
   'msgpack::v1::packer<Stream>
   &msgpack::v1::detail::packer_serializer<Stream,T>::pack(msgpack::v1::packer<Stream>
   &,const T (&))'
          with
        [
                  Stream=std::stringstream,
                   T=obj [1]
       ]
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Where did you get the msgpack package from and have you built a library or is it just a bunch of header files.

Comment: I got it from https://www.nuget.org/packages/msgpack-c/ and I am using <msgpack.hpp> headerfile....